# Find and replace multiple string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a1 in the following form in MATLAB.

```
a1{1,1} = {'x1','x2','x3'}
a1{1,2} = {'x1','x2','x3','x4'}
a1{1,3} = {'x4'}
```

I need to replace

```
'x1' with 'Text1'
'x2' with 'Text2'
'x3' with 'Text3'
'x4' with 'Text4'
```

I have tried a couple of things with no success and I am a bit lost, does anyone have any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expressions might be a way to go with this

```
a1{1,1} = {'x1','x2','x3','x4'};
a1{1,1} = regexprep(a1{1,1},'x([0-9])','text$1');
```

Will result in `a1{1,1}` containing

```
{'text1'}    {'text2'}    {'text3'}    {'text4'}
```

This will work for any single digit numerical value (0-9) that is prefixed with the letter x.